# plot_2d_separator complains when using DataFrame object (AttributeError was raised)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have few data points X collected as DataFrame object. Classes Y is a numpy array constructed depending on the values of the last column of X. I would like to visualize the decision boundaries created by 1, 3, 9 nearest neighbors model. I use X.values to be able to use Numpy methods for arrays (e.g. slicing).

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 3))
XX = X.values

for n_neighbors, ax in zip([1, 3, 9], axes):
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n_neighbors).fit(X, Y)
    mglearn.plots.plot_2d_separator(clf, XX, fill=True, eps=0.5, ax=ax, alpha=.4)
    mglearn.discrete_scatter(XX[:, 2], XX[:, 4], Y, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title("{} neighbor(s)".format(n_neighbors))
    ax.set_xlabel("nbpolys")
    ax.set_ylabel("GB time")
```

I got the following error:

```
decision_values = classifier.decision_function(X_grid)
AttributeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object has no attribute 'decision_function'
```

`decision_function` is called in `plot_2d_separator.py`

What could be the problem?

Are the parameters and their types passed to `plot_2d_separator` correct?

Thank you.

Comment: looks like you have XX is used in place of X for plot_2d_seperator. May be not a significant change

Answer (score 0):

KNN does not learn any decision function as such. Hence, the `sklearn` implementation also does not have this attribute.

You could use the predict_proba instead of decision_function

```
clf.predict_proba(x)[:, 1]
```

have a look at this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-classifier-comparison-py) for more information.

**EDIT:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
X, y = make_blobs(centers=2, random_state=42)
clf = KNeighborsClassifier().fit(X, y)
plot_2d_separator(clf, X, fill=True)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When I check [the code](https://github.com/amueller/scipy_2015_sklearn_tutorial/blob/master/notebooks/figures/plot_2d_separator.py) of function `plot_2d_seperator` `predict_proba` is called when `decision_function`... why try .... except ... is not working?

Comment: It does works fine in my end. Kindly check my update

Comment: @Fadoua, Did your problem is solved? Kindly accept the answer if it helped you in some way

Answer (score 0):

```
flg, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10,3))

for n_neighbors, ax in zip([1,3,9], axes):
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors).fit(X,y)
    mglearn.plots.plot_2d_separator(clf, X, fill=True, eps=0.5, ax=ax, alpha=0.4)
    mglearn.discrete_scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], y, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title("{} neighbor(s)" .format(n_neighbors))
    ax.set_xlabel("feature 0")
    ax.set_ylabel("feature 1")
axes[0].legend(loc=3)
```

try this

Comment: Add some explanation rather than pure code would be perferred